# How to define options programmatically

Tags: r

I am trying to define options programmatically by using a string vector as shown below. However, the option does not get defined and it returns a NULL value. Are there any best practices or functions for this?

```
f <- "z" 
options(f = TRUE)
getOption("z")
# returns NULL
```

Comment: Could you elaborate it further

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the docs:

> Options can also be passed by giving a single unnamed argument which is a named list

So you can do

```
f <- list(z = TRUE)
options(f)
getOption("z")
#> [1] TRUE
```

Or, if you want to be able to use the input format in your question, you can use the following function:

```r
prog_options <- function(...)
{
  mc <- as.list(match.call()[-1])
  names(mc) <- 
    sapply(names(mc), function(x) eval(as.name(x), envir = parent.frame()))
  options(mc)
}
```

Which allows the following:

```
f <- "z"
g <- "y"

prog_options(f = TRUE, g = "Yes")

getOption("z")
#> [1] TRUE

getOption("y")
#> [1] "Yes"
```